# Separate CSS file doesn't apply on pages included with PHP

Tags: php, css, web, php-include

I have a small website, that I wanted to "decorate" myself, but I don't get why a separate CSS file applies on the basic page and not on the included pages.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/styles.css"/>
    </head>
</html>
```

That's how I link the stylesheet.

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];

    if (!empty($page))      // if $page has a value, include it 
    {
        $page .='.php';
        include($page);
    }
    else        // otherwise, include the default page
    {
        include('news.php');        // news.php is a default page
    }
?>
```

And that's the include part.

```
#vk_profile
{
    color:#FAB41D;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#red_text
{
    color:#FF0600;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Example of CSS code.

Does someone have the answer or at least a guideline?

P.S. Never used CSS before, so I'm a total noob.

Comment: Can you post some code? CSS should work fine on includes (if that is what you're referring to?)

Comment: Way too broad. The only way to stop css from applying to an entire page is to put it in an iframe. It sounds like you're miscommunicating the issue.

Comment: This issue is certainly entirely unrelated to PHP. The only thing that matters is the actual HTML output that your various scripts produce and the actual CSS code. The PHP code will not give anything anyone to go on. Show some generated HTML and the CSS you're trying to apply.

Comment: post your code where you assume that you are linking CSS to your PHP/HTML code

Comment: Done, some parts of the code.

Comment: as you just modified your question, you can check it from your browers's inspector either your CSS is linking to your code or not

Comment: Don't do things like that :    

`$page = $_GET['page'] . '.php';
include($page);`

this is very unsecure, with this code attacker can read all php files in your system. Always verify all parameters passed in GET

Comment: Do `news.php` and `another-page.php` both load `'href="scripts/styles.css"` ?

Comment: Done, same thing... I wonder if it's not about the cache.